# Handy confirm javafx dialog in kotlin

Tags: javafx, kotlin

I'm trying to write own confirm dialog, using JavaFX, that would call lambda expression when *okButton* is pressed.

```
ConfirmDialog.show("Delete selected items?") {
    // actions...
}
```

The problem in this implementation is that `actionByConfirm` from `show()` function is never called. Please tell me, how to correct it?

```
object ConfirmDialog : UnborderedStage() {
    override val pathToScene: String
        get() = "/module/main/confirm/confirm.fxml"


    val title: Label

    val okButton: Button
    val cancelButton: Button

    var actionByConfirm: (() -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        title = scene.lookup("#title") as Label
        okButton = scene.lookup("#buttonOk") as Button
        cancelButton = scene.lookup("#buttonCancel") as Button

        okButton.setOnMouseClicked {
            actionByConfirm?.invoke()
            hide()
        }

        cancelButton.setOnMouseClicked { hide() }
    }

    fun show(title: String, actionByConfirm: () -> Unit) {
        this.title.text = title
        this.actionByConfirm = actionByConfirm
        show()
    }
}
```

*UnborderedStage is the same Stage, but with *StageStyle.UNDECORATED* and *close* action by focuse out.

Comment: Your code is fine and worked as expected in my pc with my implementation of `UnborderedStage`. Check for exceptions and post the code of class `UnborderedStage`

Comment: Try to replace `?.` with an assertion: `actionByConfirm!!.invoke()`. Does it throw?